# Lagrange multipliers problems

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I got some question about a problem I was doing.

I have to optimize $f(x,y,z) = xy + yz$, restricted to $g(x,y,z) = y^2 + z^2 = 1$, so, for Lagrange multipliers theorem, I have this:

$$ {\nabla}f = (y,x+z,y) \hspace{8mm} {\lambda}{\nabla}g = (0,2{\lambda}y,2{\lambda}z) $$

Solving for $x,y,z,{\lambda}$ I got that $(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)$, and I can't use the condition $y^2 + z^2 = 1$. Am I doing something wrong, or the function has no optimal values with that restriction?

Thanks for tour help!

Comment: Hint:  $y=0$ washes out immediately.  The second equation becomes $x+z=0$, so $x=-z$.  The third equation becomes $2\lambda z=0$, so either $z=0$ or $\lambda=0$.

Comment: So I have two solutions: one when $z = 0$ and the other when $\lambda = 0$. And I will get this three points: $(0,0,0)$, $(1,0,1)$ and $(-1,0,-1)$, is that right?

Comment: Almost; $x=-z$, so the critical points should be of the form $(\mp1,0,\pm1)$.  The case where $z=0$ should be excluded, since then the constraint fails to be satisfied.

Comment: All right, thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: You’re quite welcome.